# HP Laptop Fan bursts and then stops, trying to start but immediately puffing to an end

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, fan, hp

I have a hp pavillion dv6-7063sa bought in 2012 running windows 10 professional, so quite old now but running on an SSD so I get by.

I've recently had an issue where the fan spins to max speed after a little use for maybe a few seconds and then stops, after which it tries to start but it just puffs a little air and immediately stops.

I've cleaned the laptop fan, replaced the thermal paste and it's not necessarily even that hot when this happens. Turning it off and on makes the fan start up again but eventually it fan issue happens a few mins into it starting the laptop, or maybe a few mins into it getting hot ?

Tried pulling out CMOS battery and starting the laptop without it on battery/charger cable, but it still happened. (Someone suggested a CMOS reset could fix it)

Need help understanding how to debug what the issue is, then how to fix it.

Edit: I've got a black screen on boot about it now

> The system has detected that a cooling fan is not operating correctly.
>
> Continued operation is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior that could result in andom shutdown, data loss or possible system damage. The system will shutdown n 15 seconds. To prevent shutdown and continue operation, press the Enter key now.
>
> System Fan (90B)
>
> ENTER Continue Startup
>
> For more information, please visit: www.hp.com\gotechcenter\startup

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the fan and plugging it back in again in case it is loose? It does also looks like these fans are replaceable and not particularly expensive

Comment: I did do when I replaced the heat sink and replaced the thermal paste, after which it didn't happen for (34 days) but it suddenly started again today. Not entirely sure what's the blame, wanted to understand how to know what the issue is first before replacing it

Comment: Does the laptop show the speed of the fan and/or system temperatures, either in the BIOS or a suitable Windows program? The sensor data may be incorrect and causing issues

Comment: Any software recommendations? I don't have any installed. I opened bios menu don't see any fan options other than "fan always on"  (this apparently was enough for the fan to turn off)

Comment: SpeedFan - https://almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: Can see temperatures and that fan rpm is 0 after it stopped , added a edit to the post regarding boot error

Comment: Fans are mechanical devices and will eventually fail anyway. But unless you have an oscilloscope handy you are probably not going to be able to properly test it in isolation

Comment: Will try ordering a replacement and see how it goes, thanks

Comment: Just to update, the replacement fan is going strong and error hasn't happened since replacing. Also I found a layer of dust on the fan which I only got out after I split the fan from the heat sink pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the fan resolved the issue